# Jquery - Dynamically Add Text Over Time - 'Hacker Box' - 'Console'

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, box

So I'll be as clear and simple as possible. I love seeing inside a computer.

On my site, I want to have a wide box at the bottom of the page.

Inside this box, I'd like things going on inside the site to appear as text.

I understand how to make a jQuery event such as a click or a hover, spit out some text. What I don't understand is how to make that text go into a box that has say, 10 lines, and once the 11th line of text is created, the first slides up into the void, to be deleted.

After some searching around, I found this, which is getting closer to the goal.

```
var caption = [
"User Entered Site",
"Loading SideBar",
"Code: 01011011",
"Whatever text",
"Whatever text"
];

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
$("#message-box").html(caption[i]);
i++;
if (i == caption.length){i=0;}
}, 3 * 1000);
```

Here's the issue with the code I've found. It's actually designed for a series of changing tip at the bottom of a screen. The text will override previous text written.

Although it might be obvious I'd like to note that this sample set of text should appear in this read-only console area over time. I tried messing around with a .delay(1000) to no avail.

I don't need to get complex and write in real events for the appearing text, instead I can just create faux events - just to get the ball rolling. I figure so long as I have the main idea coded with a "false" series of "hacker-esque" codes running down this kind of... "read-only console," I'll be able to tack on some code to a new event I create in the future (click, drag, reorder, etc.) and the faux-hacker box/console will actually have some real events in it.

I may just keep faux stuff in there just to give a certain feel to this particular artistic, 'symbolically back end' website. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that might work as a basis for what you are trying to achieve. It creates a box and then displays random messages into it, scrolling them up (by deleting the first message) when the list reaches 10 messages. I haven't attempted to style it all, you could make it look a lot prettier (and use animations to remove items slowly). I've also put a limit on how many messages it displays in total (so the snippet doesn't run forever) using the counter on `i`, you could remove that in your application.

```js
var caption = [
"User Entered Site",
"Loading SideBar",
"Code: 01011011",
"Whatever text",
"Some other message"
];

var i = 0;
var h = setInterval(function() {
  // already 10 messages? if so, delete the earliest
  if ($("#message-box p").length == 10)
    $("#message-box p").first().remove();
  $("#message-box").append('<p>' + i + ': ' + caption[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)] + '</p>');
  i++;
  if (i == 20) clearInterval(h);}
, 1000);
```

```css
#message-box {
   height: 400px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message-box"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, surprised at the simplicity. I've changed it just a bit to make it dynamic for my purposes, instead of setting (Math.random()*5) I've set it to (Math.random()*caption.length

I also had a problem with randomizing the console's message's appearances, for all those interested a quick search for "jQuery setInterval to random time" will help! Danka :)